# How to annotate an SQL source file opened in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, annotate

Sorry if this question has been asked before but I did some searches and could not find any information.

When I open an SQL file in Visual Studio 2010 and right click in the editor, the "Source Control" sub-menu in the context menu is not there. I'm particularly after source code annotation.

Is there anyway to make that menu appear? I can navigate to that file in Source Control and get the context menu from there, but that is much slower than just access it directly from the editor.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I found a way. If I right click the file in the solutions explorer, I can run "Annotate" from there. However, that won't work for files that I opened outside of a project.